# Convert dataframe of two columns into fasta format

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(">Seq1", ">Seq2"), y = c("AAAA", "BBBB"))
> df1
      x    y
1 >Seq1 AAAA
2 >Seq2 BBBB
```

Wished output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x = c(">Seq1", "AAAA", ">Seq2", "BBBB"))
> df2
      x
1 >Seq1
2  AAAA
3 >Seq2
4  BBBB
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

data.frame(x = c(">Seq1", ">Seq2"), y = c("AAAA", "BBBB")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(x = c(x,y))

  x    
  <chr>
1 >Seq1
2 AAAA 
3 >Seq2
4 BBBB
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `base R`, just `t`ranspose the data, convert to a vector (`c`) and create a new data.frame

```
data.frame(x = c(t(df1)))
```

-output

```
   x
1 >Seq1
2  AAAA
3 >Seq2
4  BBBB
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(">Seq1", ">Seq2"), y = c("AAAA", "BBBB"))
```

Comment: Could we use `stack`. It gives a different order -> Is the order important in fasta format?

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyr) 
data.frame(x = c(">Seq1", ">Seq2"), y = c("AAAA", "BBBB")) |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  subset(select=-name)
```

```
  value
  <chr>
1 >Seq1
2 AAAA 
3 >Seq2
4 BBBB
```

Comment: You could do this without `subset` i.e. `pivot_longer(df1, cols = everything(), names_to = NULL)`